# NHibernate enum mapping

Tags: nhibernate

Can anybody tell me how to map enum in nhibernate using vb.net.When i search the google i found all samples in c# but i want vb.net(i am new to vb.net)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Fluent NHibernate? If not, the XML mappings are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a property node in your xml mapping file which which has the same name as the Property itself. NHibernate will pick up the type (in that case the enum) automatically using reflection.

```
<property name="YourEnumPropertyName" />
```